# OnPropertyChanged() only triggered by manually editing a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I need a TextBox which is binded to ClassA showing the sum of a variable from two Objects from ClassB.
It does only change its Value if i try to edit the TextBox manually. My problem is i dont know how i can implement a method in ClassA which listenes if the variables in ClassB are changed. I tried to make ClassB a SubClass from ClassA but then i get an StackOverflowException so that doesnt work.

---

MainWindow.xaml

---

```
<Window x:Class="INPCTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:INPCTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ClassA/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="BaseGrid" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxClassA" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Sum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1ClassB" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyClassB1.Var, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2ClassB" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding MyClassB2.Var, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

ClassA.cs

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace INPCTest
{
    public class ClassA : ObservableObject
    {

        private decimal _sum;



        public decimal Sum
        {
            get { _sum = MyClassB1.Var + MyClassB2.Var; return _sum; }
            set { _sum = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }


        public ClassB MyClassB1 { get; set; } = new ClassB(1);
        public ClassB MyClassB2 { get; set; } = new ClassB(2);

    }
}
```

---

ClassB.cs

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace INPCTest
{
    public class ClassB : ObservableObject
    {
        private decimal _var;

        public ClassB(decimal var)
        {
            _var = var;
        }

        public decimal Var
        {
            get { return _var; }
            set { _var = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }


    }
}
```

---

ObservableObject.cs

---

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace INPCTest
{
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use from `Action`.

ClassA:

```
public class ClassA : ObservableObject
{
    private decimal _sum;

    public ClassA()
    {
        MyClassB1 = new ClassB(1) {OnVarChanged = OnVarChange};
        MyClassB2 = new ClassB(2) {OnVarChanged = OnVarChange};
    }

    public decimal Sum
    {
        get { _sum = MyClassB1.Var + MyClassB2.Var; return _sum; }
        set { _sum = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }


    public ClassB MyClassB1 { get; set; }
    public ClassB MyClassB2 { get; set; }

    private void OnVarChange() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Sum));
}
```

ClassB:

```
public class ClassB : ObservableObject
{
    private decimal _var;

    public ClassB(decimal var)
    {
        _var = var;
    }

    public Action OnVarChanged { get; set; }

    public decimal Var
    {
        get { return _var; }
        set
        {
            _var = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnVarChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: nice man, thats what i needed, thank you

Comment: You're Wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

Make `ClassA` listen to each of its `ClassB` objects using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the WPF `PropertyChangedEventManager`.  When the `Var` property on either one changes, `ClassA` can raise a `PropertyChanged` event for its `Sum` property.  For example you might write a constructor for class A to do it

```
public ClassA()
{
    PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(
        MyClassB1,
        (_,_) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Sum)),
        nameof(ClassB.Var));

    PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(
        MyClassB2,
        (_,_) => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Sum)),
        nameof(ClassB.Var));
}
```

But there is a problem:  You have a public setter for  `ClassA.Sum`.  How can that possibly work if `Sum` is supposed to be the addition of each two `ClassB.Var` values?    How do you go in the other direction?

Each time someone sets `ClassA.Sum` You would have to divide the new Sum between the two `ClassB`'s somehow or the next time somebody called the getter, the value would change back.

I don't know how that's going to work.